# Should I new a utils class in es6?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have declared a class, like:

```
export default class Utils {
    static deepClone(): object {
        return {}
    }
}
```

so when I want to use deepClone, I can:

```
// First One
import Utils from './Utils';
export default class Element {
    constructor(){
        this.utils = new Utils()
    }
    create(){
        return this.utils.deepClone()
    }
}
```

or：

```
// Second One
import Utils from './Utils';
export default class Element {
    constructor(){
        this.utils = Utils
        // this is an optional
        // in my child class I need't to import Utils
        // I can use this.utils.deepClone() directly
    }
    create(){
        return Utils.deepClone()
    }
}
```

I wonder which is a better way to imply Element class

Looking forward to your reply, I can’t thank you enough

Comment: A class is useful when the instance can have own data. If not, then there's no point to a class, just use a plain object instead

Comment: ...and so the second code snippet will not work, as `deepClone` is not a static method (i.e. it is not a member of the constructor).

Comment: Thanks for ur your repl, so the Utils class is better to declare as a plain object rather than static function?

Answer (score 0):

The second way is more correct but it has a problem that you should create an instance of **Utils** class to use each property which isn't a **static** method.

The output of a class that you didn't create an instance is a function instead of an object of prototypes.

> ./Utils.js

```js
export default class Utils {
    static deepClone(): object {
        return {}
    }

   public deepExtend() {
     // deepClone code
   }
}
```

> Use in another file:

```js
import Utils from './Utils';

export default class Element {
    constructor(){
        this.utils = new Utils();
    }
    create(){
        return Utils.deepClone()
    }
    extend(){
        return this.utils.deepExtend()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would return export new of the `Utils` and I will pass it in the constructor of your `Element` as an Instance, something like:

```
IUtils = someInterface;
export default class Element {
  constructor(utils: IUtils){
    this.utils = utils;
  }
  create(){
    return this.utils.deepClone()
  }
}
```

In these way it:

1. Doesn't create new instances for nothing
2. Uses other `instances` that you can pass to your `Element` class
3. Is testable